# Remove duplicates from multidimensional arrays (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, splice

I have two arrays with times and I want to remove the duplicates, the arrays could look like this:

```
arr1 = [ ['11:00','12:00','13:00'] ]
arr2 = ['11:00'],['13:00']
```

so I've tried to first loop through the second array with 2 for loops like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < timeslotsBusy.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < timeslotsBusy[i].length; j++) {
    console.log(timeslotsBusy[i][j]);
  }
}
```

which gives me the values: 11:00, 13:00

now I have tried to go with a while loop a splice the array if the values match, but this didn't work very well. I also tried the filter method, but with no success

```
for (i = 0; i < timeslotsBusy.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < timeslotsBusy[i].length; j++) {
    for (x = 0; x < timeslotsFree.length; x++) {
      timeslotsFree = timeslotsFree[x]
      timeslotsFree = timeslotsFree.filter(val => timeslotsBusy[i][j].includes(val))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `I have tried` ... `I also tried` ... show what you tried, the code you've shown doesn't even attempt to solve the problem

Comment: Please clean up your array declaration to match your code and show the expected output. You can do this with a single `filter()` call and no for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The input array (`arr1`, `arr2`) are multi-dimensional arrays so it is needed to make them to 1d array using `Array.prototype.flat()` function.
- After making it to `1d array`, you can get the unduplicated members using `Array.prototype.filter` function. (To check if the arr2 includes the item or not, you can use `Array.prototype.includes` function.).

```js
const arr1 = [ ['11:00','12:00','13:00'] ];
const arr2 = [ ['11:00'],['13:00'] ];

const arr1Flat = arr1.flat();
const arr2Flat = arr2.flat();

const output = arr1Flat.filter((item) => !arr2Flat.includes(item));
console.log(output);
```